# Is 5V too much for a device that uses 3.5V?

Tags: voltage

I have a handheld GPS that uses 2 x1.5V batteries or a cigarette litghter plug that outputs 3.5V. I do not have a 12v source readily available but do have several USB ports that output 5V. Can I make a patch cord or do I need to reduce voltage first?

Comment: Does the hand-held GPS have a name?

Comment: Yes, it's a Lowrance airmap 600C

Comment: I'm using it in a small single seat seat sport plane

Comment: i would use an adjustable DC-DC buck converter for $1 from ebay.

Comment: I would just use batteries. You can use cheap alkaline cells or invest in rechargeable NiMH batteries which can be used many times. Otherwise, get a voltage regulator. Without knowing what is inside the GPS, it is hard to say whether 5V may harm it. Two examples of how it may cause harm: If the battery voltage is fed to an ADC, the 5V may harm the ADC input. If there are any LDO's, 5V may cause them to dissipate more power than anticipated and overheat. If they overheat, they may shut down unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3):

The *[datasheet](http://www.lowrance.com/Root/Lowrance-Documents/AirMap500_0148-382_072503.pdf)* didn't say much. I know it's the wrong model (AirMap 500), but still, no internal images. And the input power just said 3V.

Well, if I were you, I would either **A**, open the GPS and look inside and look for a Linear Voltage Regulator. If you find it then it's pretty safe to hook it up to a 5V input.

Or **B**, connect the cigarette lighter plug to a 5V supply and see if it still outputs 3.5V, if it does then I'd see if the GPS works with it as well.

Or **C**, get a Linear Voltage Regulator that converts 5V to 3.3V and burn off the excessive voltage×current in the form of heat.

Or **D**, get a step-down converter from 5V to 3.3V.

Or lastly, **E**, take my bets and connect it up to 5V and hope for the best.

Comment: Awesome answers! Thank-you very much. I'll work my way down the list.

Answer (score 3):

From [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/320688/):

> Or **C**, get a Linear Voltage Regulator that converts 5V to 3.3V and burn off the excessive voltage×current in the form of heat.

C.1 - Determine the current required, and put 2 power rectifier diodes (rated for at least 2x the current) in series with the 5 V.  The resulting voltage drop should get you close to 3.3-3.5 V.  Probably best to test it on the ground first...

Comment: That's probably the easiest solution.

Comment: This has a good chance of working just fine in the long term, and while damage cannot be absolutely ruled out, it seems unlikely. One thing that might help would be to add a resistor in parallel with the GPS. This will guarantee a minimum current through the diodes and help insure there is a voltage drop even when the GPS current is near zero.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Harry said, here are a couple of ICs that are regularly used for 5V to 3.3V regulation ([LM3940](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3940.pdf) and [LM1117](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf)).

[image: 3.3V regulation shopping cart]

Having said that, since the manual doesn't seem to specify how much current the receiver sinks, we don't know for sure that your USB port will supply the required power.

You may be able to estimate the current, given that the manual claims approx. 12 hours of run-time on AA batteries. If a AA battery is estimated to provide roughly 2000 mAh, that would suggest approx 166 mA.

This is probably conservative, but since older USB ports are only specified to 100 mA, you should be sure to use a USB 3.0 SS port (see [wikipedia: USB power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_Battery_Charging) for details)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a super simple solution, just use 3 rectifier diodes in series of the 5V power. You get about 0.65V drop across each diode, so 5V USB will be dropped to about 3.05V.

Most battery operated product that take 2 x 1.5V cells are generally designed to handle input voltage from 2V to at least 3.5V and thus work fine with poor regulation, so this simple 3 series diode scheme should work well.

Use fairly hefty diodes such as 2 Amp or 3 Amp diodes and use a 1 Amp USB charger. This way, if the output is accidentally shorted the USB charger will limit the current and the diodes will not be damaged.

Also note that while PC ports put out close to 5V, many USB chargers run their output more like 5.1V to 5.25V because the USB spec allows up to 5.25V so your device might see 3.3V with these diodes. Fresh alkaline batteries can be close to 1.6V so 3.3V isn't a big deal.

For low power applications, I've built these diodes in the power cable and just put heatshrink over them.